# Table not printing correctly

Tags: tables, mdframed, arrays

I am trying to create a table with multiple rows in a cell.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying colors by name
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}


\newmdenv[%
linecolor=ocre,
backgroundcolor=ocre!10,
linewidth=1pt]{mytablebox}

\begin{document}
    %\begin{mytablebox}
        \begin{table}
            \centering
            \caption{Crane shop activities.}
            \label{table:crane_shop_activities}
            \begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}| m{5cm}| m{5cm}|}
                \hline\\
                \textbf{Category} & \textbf{Types} & \textbf{Activities}\\
                \hline\\
                \multirow{3}{*}{Tower Car} & Mark II, III, IV & \multirow{3}{5cm}{Earlier Manufacturing, currently only POH}\\
                & DHTC (Diesel Hydraulic Tower Car) & \\
                & 8 Wheeler &\\
                \hline\\
                \multirow{2}{*}{20T Crane} & Mechanical & \multirow{2}{5cm}{Both Manufacturing and POH}\\
                & Hydraulic (retrofitting of mechanical superstructure with hydraulic one) & \\
                \hline\\
                \multirow{2}{*}{140T Crane} & Old Design Crane & POH, MLR, SP MLR\\
                & New Design Crane & Manufacturing, POH, MLR, SP MLR\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    %\end{mytablebox}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting this as output.

Please note that vertical lines are not connecting to horizontal line.
How to correct this?

I also want to make this table inside mytablebox, but when I uncomment \begin{mytablebox} it shows "Not in outer par mode. \centering" error, How can I make this work?

[image: Table output]

Comment: Remove the `\\ ` after `\hline`.

Comment: And remove the table environment to make your box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the linebreak `\\` after `\hline` (as TeXnician said) and move your environment inside the `table` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying colors by name
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}


\newmdenv[%
linecolor=ocre,
backgroundcolor=ocre!10,
linewidth=1pt]{mytablebox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Crane shop activities.}
        \label{table:crane_shop_activities}
        \begin{mytablebox}
            \begin{tabular}{|m{15mm}| m{40mm}| m{45mm}|}
                \hline
                \textbf{Category} & \textbf{Types} & \textbf{Activities}\\
                \hline
                \multirow{3}{*}{Tower Car} & Mark II, III, IV & \multirow{3}{5cm}{Earlier Manufacturing, currently only POH}\\
                & DHTC (Diesel Hydraulic Tower Car) & \\
                & 8 Wheeler &\\
                \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{20T Crane} & Mechanical & \multirow{2}{5cm}{Both Manufacturing and POH}\\
                & Hydraulic (retrofitting of mechanical superstructure with hydraulic one) & \\
                \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{140T Crane} & Old Design Crane & POH, MLR, SP MLR\\
                & New Design Crane & Manufacturing, POH, MLR, SP MLR\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{mytablebox}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your space between the line and the text is produced by an superfluous line break.

And you cannot use a floating environment in a mdframed box. Just remove it and use `\captionof` instead.

You will then notice that your table is too wide for your box (wider than the text width).

[image: table and mdframed]

You can easily get rid of that by choosing a `\textwidth` which is wider or correcting your columns. With `m{4cm}` (and with page margins to show that it fits):

[image: corrected]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying colors by name
\usepackage{caption}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}


\newmdenv[%
linecolor=ocre,
backgroundcolor=ocre!10,
linewidth=1pt]{mytablebox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mytablebox}
            \centering
            \captionof{table}{Crane shop activities.}
            \label{table:crane_shop_activities}
            \begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}| m{5cm}| m{5cm}|}
                \hline
                \textbf{Category} & \textbf{Types} & \textbf{Activities}\\
                \hline
                \multirow{3}{*}{Tower Car} & Mark II, III, IV & \multirow{3}{5cm}{Earlier Manufacturing, currently only POH}\\
                & DHTC (Diesel Hydraulic Tower Car) & \\
                & 8 Wheeler &\\
                \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{20T Crane} & Mechanical & \multirow{2}{5cm}{Both Manufacturing and POH}\\
                & Hydraulic (retrofitting of mechanical superstructure with hydraulic one) & \\
                \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{140T Crane} & Old Design Crane & POH, MLR, SP MLR\\
                & New Design Crane & Manufacturing, POH, MLR, SP MLR\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
    \end{mytablebox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Removed my answer in which I solved the issue but with bad practices.